# NHibernate: how to keep reference to last added element in collection?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a collection of items in one object and I need to keep reference to the last added item to the collection, so I am doing like this:

```
public class VehicleMap : BaseUniqueNamedEntityMap<Vehicle>
    {
        public VehicleMap():
            base("vehicle_id", 40)
        {
            Not.LazyLoad();                

            //The main collection of items
            HasMany(x => x.mVehicleModels)                                        
                .OrderBy("date asc")
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()                    
                .LazyLoad()
                .KeyColumn("vehicle_id");

            //Always updated to the last added item
            References(x => x.mCurrentModel)
                .Column("current_vehicle_model_relation_id")
                .Cascade.None()
                .Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
```

And the Vehicle class looks like this:

```
  public class Vehicle : BaseUniqueNamedEntity
{        
    private IList<VehicleModelItem> mVehicleModels = new List<VehicleModelItem>();

    [NotNull()]
    private VehicleModelItem mCurrentModel;

    public VehicleModel Model
    {
        get { return mCurrentModel.VehicleModel; }

        set 
        {
            //Check null before checking if values change, so we catch exceptions on constructor also
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Vehicle model cannot be null");                

                //When model is set, we update current model and insert it on list
                mCurrentModel = new VehicleModelItem(this, value);
                mVehicleModels.Add(mCurrentModel);
                value.AddVehicleModelItem(mCurrentModel);                    
        }
    }          
}
```

VehicleModelItem mapping:

```
public VehicleModelItemMap() :
            base("vehicle_model_relation_id")
        {
            Not.LazyLoad();                

            References(x => x.mVehicleModel)
                .Column("vehicle_model_id")
                .Cascade.None()
                .LazyLoad(Laziness.Proxy)
                .Not.Nullable();

            Map(x => x.mDate)
                .Column("date")
                .Not.Nullable();
        }
```

The problem is, if I create a new vehicle, like:

```
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.Model = anyExitingVehicleModel;

session.save(vehicle);
```

I get an "null or transient object set to not null property", in this case for the property Vehicle in the VehicleModelItem.

The problem is related to the mCurrenveVehicleModel property in vehicle, if I removed it, everything works find, but I could not track the last added item (at least not by this way).

Is there anyway that I can make this work without needing to call save for both the VehicleModelItem and vehicle?

I tried several combinations of Cascade on those collections, but without success.

Thank you

Comment: What about `Cascade.SaveUpdate()` on the many-to-one? But, there might be an issue with duplicate inserts if you cascade from both the collection and the many-to-one. Probably best to issue manual save on the VehicleModelItem...

Comment: @dotjoe: I think the same, I will need a separate save, it looks like nhibernate is getting lost with the "double reference" to the same item.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your VehicleMap to this:

```
public class VehicleMap : BaseUniqueNamedEntityMap<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMap():
        base("vehicle_id", 40)
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();                

        //The main collection of items
        HasMany(x => x.mVehicleModels)                                        
            .OrderBy("date asc")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()                    
            .LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumn("vehicle_id")
            .Inverse();

        //Always updated to the last added item
        References(x => x.mCurrentModel)
            .Column("current_vehicle_model_relation_id")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Not.Insert();
    }
}
```

This is something similar to what I do except I am manually setting the 'referenced' portion rather than including it in a setter.  The only downside to this is that with the 'Inverse' set to true, you have to manually specify the parent on the VehicleModelItem.  Since the constructor is passing in that reference, I'm assuming you are already doing that.

Comment: thank you so much, but still getting the "null or transient" error. It looks like nhibernate is lost because of the double reference, but I could not find a way to give it a hint on how to use it.

Comment: @bcsanches Try removing 'Cascade.None()' from the 'references' on the  VehicleModelItemMap along with the other changes I proposed in my answer.  I have this exact setup (except instead of keeping track of the 'last' item, I am keeping track of a 'default' item).  I'm basically trying to make our mappings the same as mine works perfectly.

Comment: thanks again. I tried, so far it looks exactly like you sugested: http://pastebin.com/jCckwH4s . Perhaps I am missing some other detail. I do set all the references on the constructor, as you imagined.

Comment: @bcsanches Sorry, I didn't notice until now that you have both a 'VehicleModel' and 'VehicleModelItem' type.  If your collection of 'Models' on a vehicle is 'owned' by the vehicle (no other vehicle will have the same 'model' instance), you should have a collection of 'VehicleModel' on your vehicle.  If a model is used on another vehicle, you should be mapping it as a HasManyToMany.  Either way, you should probably get rid of 'VehicleModelItem.'

Comment: No problem, it is a ManyToMany, but I created my own class to manage the many to many so I can stuff some extra properties there, like creation date.

Comment: @bcsanches I've updated my strategy for this problem by changing my answer :)

Comment: I simple to do not feel confident to trust the date for this, thats why I would prefer a direct "pointer" to show this. Another alternative that I thought was to have a bool on the VehileModelItem to indicate the current one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15191/discussion-between-docmanhattan-and-bcsanches)